# Replacing curly apostrophes and quotes with straight apostrophes and quotes using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to replace all curly apostrophes/quotes with straight ones using gsub for my homework. When I run the following code below, I run into a few issues provided in the screenshot below.

`gsub("’","'",prank_df$Prank, ignore.case=TRUE)
gsub("‘","'",prank_df$Prank, ignore.case=TRUE)
gsub('“','"',prank_df$Prank, ignore.case=TRUE)`

This is the output before attempting the functions above:
[image]

This is the result when running the gsubs above:

[image]

Comment: Please share a reproducible example. Also are you assigning the data back? `prank_df$Prank <- gsub("’","'",prank_df$Prank, ignore.case=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a way to flexibly `gsub` your expressions. You can have a look at the `qdap::mgsub` function that allows vectorized patterns, replacements and character object to be inspected. I can give you a silly example:

```r
str <- "This string ‘has’ non “standard“ elements"

df = data.frame(str = rep(str,5))

qdap::mgsub(pattern = c("‘", "’", '“'),
      replacement = c("'","'",'"'),
      df$str)
[1] "This string 'has' non \"standard\" elements" "This string 'has' non \"standard\" elements"
[3] "This string 'has' non \"standard\" elements" "This string 'has' non \"standard\" elements"
[5] "This string 'has' non \"standard\" elements"
```

By the way, if you want big quotations (`"`) within your string, `R` will espace them. When using a printing function, e.g. `cat`, you will see the expected output:

```r
cat(qdap::mgsub(pattern = c("‘", "’", '“'),
+             replacement = c("'","'",'"'),
+             df$str), sep = "\n")
This string 'has' non "standard" elements
This string 'has' non "standard" elements
This string 'has' non "standard" elements
This string 'has' non "standard" elements
This string 'has' non "standard" elements
```

Comment: qdap requires Java, bit of a high price to pay, for a curly apostrophe.. No java installed, couldn't test the solution. But I don't have any other ideas, struggling with the same issue.